# Eclipse/ RapidClipse X 10.2.2 Exception occurred in listener of Java element change notification

Tags: java, eclipse, rapidclipse

I got in eclipse *logfile* following errors:

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   com.rapidclipse.commons.jdt.JDTUtils.isAssignmentCompatible(JDTUtils.java:752)
>     at
>   com.rapidclipse.ide.ui.editor.annotations.sourcewizard.reports.ReportSourceWizardHandler.createIndicator(ReportSourceWizardHandler.java:32)
>     at
>   com.rapidclipse.commons.ui.editor.java.annotations.sourcewizard.SourceWizardAnnotationManager$SourceWizardVisitor.visit(SourceWizardAnnotationManager.java:152)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.MethodInvocation.accept0(MethodInvocation.java:220)
>     at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.accept(ASTNode.java:2927)   at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.acceptChild(ASTNode.java:2975)   at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.MethodInvocation.accept0(MethodInvocation.java:223)
>     at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.accept(ASTNode.java:2927)   at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.acceptChild(ASTNode.java:2975)   at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.MethodInvocation.accept0(MethodInvocation.java:223)
>     at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.accept(ASTNode.java:2927)   at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.acceptChildren(ASTNode.java:2998)    at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.MethodInvocation.accept0(MethodInvocation.java:228)
>     at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.accept(ASTNode.java:2927)   at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.acceptChild(ASTNode.java:2975)   at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ExpressionStatement.accept0(ExpressionStatement.java:136)
>     at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.accept(ASTNode.java:2927)   at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.acceptChildren(ASTNode.java:2998)    at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.Block.accept0(Block.java:128)    at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.accept(ASTNode.java:2927)    at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.acceptChild(ASTNode.java:2975)   at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.MethodDeclaration.accept0(MethodDeclaration.java:617)
>     at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.accept(ASTNode.java:2927)   at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.acceptChildren(ASTNode.java:2998)    at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.TypeDeclaration.accept0(TypeDeclaration.java:447)
>     at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.accept(ASTNode.java:2927)   at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.acceptChildren(ASTNode.java:2998)    at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.CompilationUnit.accept0(CompilationUnit.java:258)
>     at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.accept(ASTNode.java:2927)   at
>   com.rapidclipse.commons.ui.editor.java.annotations.sourcewizard.SourceWizardAnnotationManager.collectAnnotations(SourceWizardAnnotationManager.java:127)
>     at
>   com.rapidclipse.commons.ui.editor.java.annotations.ASTBasedAnnotationManager.reconciled(ASTBasedAnnotationManager.java:41)
>     at
>   com.rapidclipse.commons.ui.editor.java.RapidClipseCompilationUnitEditor.reconciled(RapidClipseCompilationUnitEditor.java:662)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.JavaReconcilingStrategy.reconciled(JavaReconcilingStrategy.java:222)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.JavaCompositeReconcilingStrategy.reconciled(JavaCompositeReconcilingStrategy.java:167)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.JavaCompositeReconcilingStrategy.reconcile(JavaCompositeReconcilingStrategy.java:115)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.text.reconciler.MonoReconciler.process(MonoReconciler.java:76)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.text.reconciler.AbstractReconciler$BackgroundThread.run(AbstractReconciler.java:210)
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core.internal.AbstractJpaProject.compilationUnitResourceExists(AbstractJpaProject.java:1438)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core.internal.AbstractJpaProject.javaCompilationUnitDeltaIsRelevant(AbstractJpaProject.java:1427)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core.internal.InternalJpaProjectManager.javaCompilationUnitDeltaIsRelevant(InternalJpaProjectManager.java:1008)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core.internal.InternalJpaProjectManager.handleJavaCompilationUnitDelta(InternalJpaProjectManager.java:1000)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core.internal.InternalJpaProjectManager.handleJavaDelta(InternalJpaProjectManager.java:935)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core.internal.InternalJpaProjectManager.handleJavaElementChangedEvent(InternalJpaProjectManager.java:918)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core.internal.InternalJpaProjectManager.javaElementChanged(InternalJpaProjectManager.java:861)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core.internal.InternalJpaProjectManager$JavaElementChangeListener.elementChanged(InternalJpaProjectManager.java:1387)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.DeltaProcessor$3.run(DeltaProcessor.java:1755)
>     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)  at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.DeltaProcessor.notifyListeners(DeltaProcessor.java:1743)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.DeltaProcessor.fireReconcileDelta(DeltaProcessor.java:1594)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.DeltaProcessor.fire(DeltaProcessor.java:1553)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.run(JavaModelOperation.java:777)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.runOperation(JavaModelOperation.java:802)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnit.reconcile(CompilationUnit.java:1315)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.JavaReconcilingStrategy.reconcile(JavaReconcilingStrategy.java:131)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.JavaReconcilingStrategy.access$0(JavaReconcilingStrategy.java:113)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.JavaReconcilingStrategy$1.run(JavaReconcilingStrategy.java:93)
>     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)  at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.JavaReconcilingStrategy.reconcile(JavaReconcilingStrategy.java:90)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.JavaReconcilingStrategy.reconcile(JavaReconcilingStrategy.java:157)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.CompositeReconcilingStrategy.reconcile(CompositeReconcilingStrategy.java:94)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.JavaCompositeReconcilingStrategy.reconcile(JavaCompositeReconcilingStrategy.java:112)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.text.reconciler.MonoReconciler.process(MonoReconciler.java:76)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.text.reconciler.AbstractReconciler$BackgroundThread.run(AbstractReconciler.java:210)
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core.internal.AbstractJpaProject.compilationUnitResourceExists(AbstractJpaProject.java:1438)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core.internal.AbstractJpaProject.javaCompilationUnitDeltaIsRelevant(AbstractJpaProject.java:1427)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core.internal.InternalJpaProjectManager.javaCompilationUnitDeltaIsRelevant(InternalJpaProjectManager.java:1008)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core.internal.InternalJpaProjectManager.handleJavaCompilationUnitDelta(InternalJpaProjectManager.java:1000)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core.internal.InternalJpaProjectManager.handleJavaDelta(InternalJpaProjectManager.java:935)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core.internal.InternalJpaProjectManager.handleJavaElementChangedEvent(InternalJpaProjectManager.java:918)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core.internal.InternalJpaProjectManager.javaElementChanged(InternalJpaProjectManager.java:861)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core.internal.InternalJpaProjectManager$JavaElementChangeListener.elementChanged(InternalJpaProjectManager.java:1387)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.DeltaProcessor$3.run(DeltaProcessor.java:1755)
>     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)  at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.DeltaProcessor.notifyListeners(DeltaProcessor.java:1743)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.DeltaProcessor.fireReconcileDelta(DeltaProcessor.java:1594)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.DeltaProcessor.fire(DeltaProcessor.java:1553)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.run(JavaModelOperation.java:777)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.runOperation(JavaModelOperation.java:802)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnit.reconcile(CompilationUnit.java:1315)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.JavaReconcilingStrategy.reconcile(JavaReconcilingStrategy.java:131)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.JavaReconcilingStrategy.access$0(JavaReconcilingStrategy.java:113)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.JavaReconcilingStrategy$1.run(JavaReconcilingStrategy.java:93)
>     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)  at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.JavaReconcilingStrategy.reconcile(JavaReconcilingStrategy.java:90)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.JavaReconcilingStrategy.initialReconcile(JavaReconcilingStrategy.java:188)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.CompositeReconcilingStrategy.initialReconcile(CompositeReconcilingStrategy.java:125)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.JavaCompositeReconcilingStrategy.initialReconcile(JavaCompositeReconcilingStrategy.java:144)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.text.reconciler.MonoReconciler.initialProcess(MonoReconciler.java:98)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.JavaReconciler.initialProcess(JavaReconciler.java:423)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.text.reconciler.AbstractReconciler$BackgroundThread.run(AbstractReconciler.java:177)

I am using RapidClipseX V10.2.2 on LinuxMint 19.03
Both are completely new and fresh installations

Eclipse Java Development Tools Version: 3.18.300
Eclipse Platform Version: 4.15.0.v2
Eclipse RCP Version: 4.15.0.v2

My Session Data:

> eclipse.buildId=4.15.0.I20200305-0155 java.version=11.0.7
>   java.vendor=Ubuntu BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64,
>   WS=gtk, NL=de_DE Framework arguments:  -product
>   com.rapidclipse.ide.product Command-line arguments:  -data
>   file:/home/user/rcx_ws2/ -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product
>   com.rapidclipse.ide.product

Are there any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Must be the issue of Rapidclipse Sir of Linux version. Can you try and download the new version that came out on 11th May 2021, please.

Comment: In meantime I use the last Version of RapidClipse X. The error did not happend again.

Answer (score 0):

In meantime I use the last Version of RapidClipse X. The error did not happend again.